# What is the difference between oral and verbal?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, word-meaning

What is the difference between the words *verbal* and *oral*?
I am confused a lot about these words and I would be grateful for your effort if you try to write about the difference.

Comment: Can you quote some dictionary entries you checked and explain why they're still confusing?

Comment: oral quiz and  verbal quiz what is the difference

Comment: @NaserMarzog Though *oral* and *verbal* can overlap, they don't always mean the same thing. When they're used with *quiz*, "verbal quiz" will focus on words (as in Sander's answer), whereas "oral quiz" will be spoken. I'd recommend learning about [collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation). A well-known example is *strong* and *powerful*. Though both mean about the same, we don't say *\*powerful tea*, we say *strong tea*. On the other hand, we don't say *\*strong computers*, we say *powerful computers*.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256370). The EL&U question *[Orally or Verbally](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125589/)* may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between the two terms is as follows:

***Verbal*** applies to everything that is turned into **words**. It doesn't matter if these are ***written*** words **or** ***spoken*** ones.

***Oral***, on the other hand, has nothing to do with written words. In the context of language it refers to anything that is ***spoken***. In other context it can also refer to things that are related to *the mouth* or the way certain medication is taken (oral medication = medication taken via the mouth).

Normally, *verbal* is **not used** to refer to *spoken* text, even though it can. In this case it is better to use *oral* instead to more clear.

Simply put:

- Verbal = **words**, written and spoken
- Oral = anything **spoken**

Comment: sory but i didn't understand you can you explain it using simpler words

Comment: I put a simplified explanation at the bottom of my answer

Comment: In long man dictionary  verbal means spoken rather than writing                                       and oral mean spoken not written so what is the difference

Comment: @Sander It might be good to clarify that *verbal* can take the same meaning as *oral* in some contexts. Your answer only gives the most common meaning of the two words.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion is caused by the definition #3 from the [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbal) of the word **verbal**:

> 3. Expressed in spoken rather than written words; oral: a verbal contract.

Anyway,

> This may seem like a morass, but don't despair. Avoiding this accident of style is easier than you may think. Just remember that oral refers to spoken words, written refers to written words, and verbal refers to anything expressed in words, whether spoken or written.

(Charles Harrington Elster, The Accidents of Style: Good Advice on How Not to Write Badly. St. Martin's Press, 2010).

In other words, the adjective [oral](http://grammar.about.com/od/alightersideofwriting/a/Oral-And-Verbal.htm) means pertaining to speech or to the mouth).

The adjective verbal means pertaining to words, whether written or spoken (though verbal is sometimes treated as a synonym for oral).

Comment: In long man dictionary  verbal means spoken rather than writing                                       and oral mean spoken not written so what is the difference

Comment: If you were supposed to learn my language I could have understood your confusion since verbal means always oral [verba volant, scripta manem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verba_volant,_scripta_manent). But English is different, only in some specific instances verbal means oral. However, oral doesn’t always mean verbal. When referring to mouth you use oral: *pills orally taken* not verbally.